# FCM migration without losing the old token

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I have somewhat of an edge case, we're migrating to firebase, but our DB is weird and we're having some trouble making this transition smooth. Our table used to be `[user-id, device-id]`, and the backend does a `select * where user-id = foo`, then loops the result and sends a push to each device-id. These ids can be GCM or APNS tokens, the backend checks where to send it based on the format.
To migrate, we added a column: firebase-id. For our iOS app we can call a method to get the old device-id. Now that we're using firebase we retrieve this old token and the new firebase one, we then send both of them to the backend, if the old token already existed we update the row and add the new firebase token to the new column, if the old token is new we ignore it and create a new row with the firebase token.
For sending, we changed the code to see if a row has a firebase id, if it does we send the push to firebase, otherwise we send it using the old way.

The idea here was to keep supporting users with old tokens, because some might update the app on one device, but not on another. We could have cleaned all old tokens of one user when they had a firebase id, but then they would stop receiving notifications on any devices that don't have the updated app. We can't simply add a row and leave the old ones, because then users would receive two notifications.

What we did works fine for iOS, we have it in place and everything is going according to plan. When they update they register a new firebase token and add it to the row that had the old device token of the current device.
But I want to implement the same for Android now, and I don't seem to be able to get the old token. FCM specifies being unable to run next to the old GCM SDK, I can't find a function to retrieve the old token via the FCM SDK, we don't have it cached anywhere (well, in the DB, but that's not coupled to the device so we wouldn't know which row to update). I need the old token in an app that already uses FCM, so I can send both tokens to the backend at once and it can update the row with the old token.

How can I retrieve the old GCM token when already using firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not built into your previous codebase, I can't think of an easy way to associate the GCM token with Firebase.

However, GCM and FCM tokens both work to send to devices from the FCM endpoint. Assuming you're using the same project for GCM and Firebase, you can take advantage of this. When a user updates to the new version of your app that uses FCM, when the token refreshes, the previous GCM token will be invalidated. You could send a message to both GCM and FCM tokens. Since you get a response telling you if tokens are invalid, as the GCM tokens come back invalidated over time when users update, you could remove them from your database.

I realize it's not an elegant solution, but it could work.

Comment: Yes this is our backup plan, the main problem with it is the user will receive double pushes if they have a GCM and FCM token for the same device in the DB. So  I have to make a mechanism to catch that. I was hoping firebase would expose some kind of method somewhere to fetch the old token.

Comment: They can't have both a GCM and FCM token if the client only has one of these. The one token will be invalidated upon refresh.